# Usage of plone.resource for front end developers

Tags: plone

plone.resource provides simple way to drop in static media files in your Plone

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.resource

However, the usage of plone.resource has not been explained from the system admin / front end developer perspective. The current documentation outlines the process from Zope 3 developer perspective only and does not give a full story how to add egg to the buildout, how to connect files to portal_javascript and so on.

What are the best practice just to "drop in a static media folder" for your Plone, where you then can register entries for portal_css and portal_javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plone.resource is a framework component. The documentation you seek needs to sit in packages that use plone.resource to accomplish the type of "admin experience" you are describing. The most obvious example is plone.app.theming, which does have this type of information in its documentation.

Comment: Thank you! This was not entirely clear from the package README context.